# Aggregation of aggregation in Kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation

I am trying to add some metrics on top of a set of aggregations in Kibana, however I do not know to do that. 
For example, my data looks like:

```
{{"A": 12, "B": 15, "month": "July"  }, 
 {"A": 5, "B": 98,  "month": "August"},
 {"A": 54, "B": 21, "month": "July"  },
 {"A": 53, "B": 4,  "month": "August"},
 {"A": 15, "B": 24, "month": "August"},
 {"A": 45, "B": 33, "month": "July"  },
 {"A": 25, "B": 56, "month": "August"},
 {"A": 8, "B": 23,  "month": "August"},
 {"A": 7, "B": 78,  "month": "July"  }}
```

I want to draw a line graph to show SUM(A)/SUM(B) over months. So the Y axis is `SUM(A)/SUM(B) per month` in this example. This is kind of applying aggregation functions over aggregation. I know that we can have aggregation of aggregation in elastic search, but what about in Kibana Visualization? Is it possible to do that in current version of Kibana (6.3)? Thanks!   [image]

Comment: Is this `{"A": 12, "B": 15, "month": "July"  }` one document?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes. Let's assume each record is one document

Comment: It kind of matters. For one, you have a field there called `month`; as you know, Kibana is about time series. The `month` field is a string, not a `date`. So, having a time series over a string that has in it month names isn't gonna cut it.

Comment: I looked at this a bit. Even if the `month` or whatever date field you have in there, be it `date` or not, this kind of aggregation can be done with [`bucket_script` aggregation from Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html). Which is not yet available in Kibana, it seems: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4707.

Comment: Otherwise, you could use Timelion with something like this `.es(index=test,metric=sum:A,timefield=month).divide(.es(index=test,metric=sum:B,timefield=month))`. But `month` has to be a time field, as I mentioned previously. It can be as easy as `"month":{"type":"date","format":"yyyy-MMM"}` (meaning year and month name).

Comment: @AndreiStefan  thanks for your comments. Actually, I was looking for a tricky way to visualize bucket_script in Kibana, which seems, based on the link you shared, has not been implemented in Kibana yet. I am looking into your last comment to see whether or not I can use Timelion for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as pointed out in the comments already, this requires the [`bucket_script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) aggregation in Elasticsearch. This is currently not available for "classical charts" in Kibana (see [kibana/#4707](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4707)).

You can either solve this using Timelion with the expression (as pointed out by Andrei above) and switch your interval to 1M in the interval chooser in the Editor (or the Timelion App):

`.es(index=test,metric=sum:A,timefield=month).divide(.es(index=test,metric=sum:B,timefield=month))`

Another solution would be to use the "Visual Builder" for which the configuration would look as follows:

[image: Editor configuration TSVB]

You should also select `interval` size of `1M` under the "Panel Options" in case you want monthly values.